# IBM Rhapsody: How to use non-member functions in sequence diagrams?

Tags: interface, uml, sequence-diagram, rhapsody, non-member-functions

In Rhapsody I have designed an interface which consists of an interface class and a couple of non-member functions. These non-member functions I've put directly into a package which is parallel to the parent package of the interface class. I want to generate code from this interface which works fine.

But I have the problem that I'm not able to select the non-member functions for messages in sequence diagrams. This is because I cannot assign the package to the contract of a port and also I cannot make a realization relation between some class and the package.

So is there any way to bring these non-member functions into the "Select Message" menu for sequence diagrams?

Answer (score 0):

> But I have the problem that I'm not able to select the non-member functions for messages in sequence diagrams.

That's intended. How do you expect the sequence diagram to look like?
Please provide a sketch. I am afraid that would violate the UML spec.

A Sequence Diagram focuses on the **Message interchange between Lifelines**.
A Lifeline describes the time-line for a process.
In *Rhapsody*, a **Lifeline represents the object of a classifier**.

A asynchronous Message can be seen as a **call of a function on the Message receiver** (where the Message receiver is a Lifeline).

Your non-member functions do not belong to any Lifeline and hence can not be shown as a Message on a sequence diagram.

What are the lifelines in your sequence diagram?

> So is there any way to bring these non-member functions into the "Select Message" menu for sequence diagrams?

No, because they aren't members of a classifier.

Comment: The lifeline I want to send a message to (and for which I want to select a non-member function) represents a component which implements an interface consisting both of member functions (from an interface class) as well as non-member functions.

Comment: @J.R. *"an interface consisting both of member functions as well as non-member functions"* does not make sense to me, if you are talking about UML-interfaces.

Comment: It's not necessarily one interface class only, I'm talking about an interface on a more high/logical level (for me an interface can also consist of multiple interface classes or - as mentioned above - of an interface class and non-member functions). At the end I want to be able to achieve two things:
1) use the methods in sequence diagrams
2) generate code out of the interface